# How to customize the orientation of individual elements in a custom linear layout in a recyclerView Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to change the alignment of the row layout elements in a linear RecyclerView this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="94dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:id="@+id/taskThumbnailImg"
            android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="227dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/taskCustomerName"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/taskLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Which currently displays Horizontally as: 
[image: Undesired Layout]

But this is how I wish to create a layout:

[image]

This is neither vertical or horizontal. What do I need to alter to create this layout?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinearLayout` will let you add views either horizontally or vertically. Though you can achive this usig `LinearLayout`, it's not recomended since more effeciant layouts are exists.

Try to learn different [Layouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout) android uses. Then you'll understand better which will suits you.

I'll suggest simple [`RelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative) or [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) for complex cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Linear Layout inside the Linear layout to align the items horizontally. Please add margins and widths for the TextViews as you need.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:id="@+id/taskThumbnailImg"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:text="taskCustomerName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/taskCustomerName"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="taskLocation"
            android:id="@+id/taskLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```